# How to correctly use coffeescript / sass ( compiled languages ) with Google Polymer?

Tags: coffeescript, sass, polymer

I'm *really* new to both CoffeeScript and Sass, but am trying to work my way through a test project with both them and Google Polymer in order to become more familiar with each. I am having a little bit of confusion of how to set up my project, however.

In the examples for `custom-elements` with Google Polymer they have you use embedded Javascript code in order to initialize elements like so:

```
<script>
  Polymer ({
    is: 'id-here'
  });
</script>
```

Which is all well and good, but this will not work with CoffeeScript, which I have to compile to JS before use. What is the best practice to include something like this —

```
Polymer
  is: "id-here"
  properties:
    etc
```

— in my project using an external CoffeeScript file instead of embedded Javascript code? Is it best to load the external compiled .js file into my `custom-element` or would that try to load it every time I use the custom element?

I'm also not sure how I am supposed to use `sass` with custom-elements, also, since those are also compiled before use.

Very confused here, any help or documentation about using **compiled languages with Google Polymer** would be appreciated, as google searches have yielded nothing. Thank you!

Comment: Do not ask about multiple unrelated problems in the same question (your question starts off describing a Polymer problem, then meanders into an unrelated Sass problem).

Comment: Well.. maybe I should word it differently but my problem lies in using compiled languages with Polymer, so Sass is still entirely relevant. I'll try editing for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your files separate. Process them separately. Combine them at the end as a build step.

**Example polymer element:**

```
<dom-module id="foo-bar" assetpath="/">
  <template>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" media="all" href="foo-bar.css" />
    <div>[[formatName(name)]]
    <div>[[employer]]
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[addresses]]">
      <div>[[item.street]</div>
      <div>[[item.city]], [[item.state]] [[item.zip]]</div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script src="foo-bar.js"></script>
</dom-module>
```

You can now use coffeescript/typescript/etc to generate your `foo-bar.js` file. Sass/Less/etc to create your `foo-bar.css` file.

During final builds, tools like Vulcanize can inline all of your generated files.